# How to print random from table in a procedure oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Let's say I have a table **child** and I want in a procedure to select random from 1 to 5, random values from the table and print them. How can i do it?

```
create table child(name varchar2(20), age number);
```

```
insert into child(name, age) values('A',5);
insert into child(name, age) values('B',12);
insert into child(name, age) values('C',7);
insert into child(name, age) values('D',4);
```

```
create or replace procedure random_child
as
 l_name child.name%type;
 l_age child.age%type;
begin
  for i in(select dbms_random.value(1,5) 
           from (select name from child sample(50)))
loop
 DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(i.name);
end loop;
end;
```

It gives me a **PLS-00302: name must be declared**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE random_child
AS
BEGIN
  FOR i in(
    SELECT name,
           FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,6)) AS value
    FROM   child
    SAMPLE(50)
  )
  LOOP
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(i.name || ' ' || i.value);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
BEGIN
  random_child();
END;
/
```

May randomly output:

> ```
> B 3
> C 2
> D 2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3470b5e38178602c331829fbef0b0128)*

Answer (score 1):

There's no `i.name` there; alias is missing at the end of line #6:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure random_child
  2  as
  3   l_name child.name%type;
  4   l_age child.age%type;
  5  begin
  6    for i in(select dbms_random.value(1,5)  as name  --> here
  7             from (select name from child sample(50)))
  8  loop
  9   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(i.name);
 10  end loop;
 11  end;
 12  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec random_child
1,30966411991963041689918865935551009464
1,13993832387089615287177388489291237644
3,85292920191145794430114472793297022632

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```